# Rails, fields_for, merging records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, fields-for

I'm using fields_for(), not for a nested form, but to display a form containing joined items. I need to display data from @seasons, that help me filling drinks...

```
<% @seasons do |season| %>  
      
   <%= fields_for "drinks[]", season.drink do |f| %>

      ...
      <%= f.select :optimized_region_id ... %>
      ...

   <% end %>
<% end %>
```

It works well.
However, even if @seasons are never the same, some season.drink could be the sames items as they are "parent" relations. (same season.drink.id)
It's not a problem for me.

My issue is that the form sends this:

```
drinks"=>{
"e80e15c1-a5d4-4df4-80c6-2efa96e39793"=>{"optimized_status"=>"1", "optimized_nickname"=>"Alex"}, 
"b7501fe0-3a78-412e-88d5-e7643d761a98"=>{"optimized_status"=>"1", "optimized_nickname"=>"Paul"}
...
}
```

and should send this:

```
drinks"=>{
"e80e15c1-a5d4-4df4-80c6-2efa96e39793"=>{"optimized_status"=>"1", "optimized_nickname"=>"Alex"}, 
"e80e15c1-a5d4-4df4-80c6-2efa96e39793"=>{"optimized_status"=>"0", "optimized_nickname"=>"Alex"}, 
"b7501fe0-3a78-412e-88d5-e7643d761a98"=>{"optimized_status"=>"1", "optimized_nickname"=>"Paul"}
...
}
```

It seems that Rails is merging drinks that have the same id when the form is sent. Is there a possibility to avoid this and send all drinks even if they have the same drink.id ?

Comment: Using arrays (`[]`) in parameter pairs is not a good idea for anything except simple values - when you pass nested objects they will invariable collide as the parameter parser just can't tell them apart. Instead rails uses a hash with the keys (`drinks[0]...`, `drinks[1]...`). You should not have to manually iterate across the collection in the first place. Just pass it to fields for as `<%= fields_for :drinks, @drinks do |f| %>...`.

Comment: Thanks Max. Not sure to understand. I need to send an array of drinks in the form. Using your code doesn't build an array and send only the last drink of the form. Consider my form as a grid of drinks to send to the controller.

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround setting the season_id in the [] :

```
<%= fields_for "drinks[#{season.id}]", record.drink do |f| %>
```

Now, all my drinks are sent from the form, evene the ones with same id.